# Iterator traits on pointer to volatile

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer, volatile

This code

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename std::iterator_traits<volatile int *>::value_type, volatile int>);
```

compiles on latest GCC and clang, but fails on MSVC 2019, that seems to remove `volatile` qualifier. See [here on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3a7Mncqh4).

The `const` is removed, due to the standard specialization of [std::iterator_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) for `const T*` and `T*`, but I think `volatile` should be kept.

Who is right?

**Edit:** I'm compiling with C++17.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/2612

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/h3rTWrvvM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the link comment by @康桓瑋 to an answer:

This is [LWG issue 2952](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2952). Before its resolution `value_type` would be `volatile`-qualified, but its resolution changes it to remove the `volatile` qualification.

The resolution is incorporated into C++20 and MSVC, GCC and Clang all seem to implement it as such. (Meaning that the `static_assert` in the question fails when the compiler is set to C++20 mode.)

With regards to whether the resolution should be applied as a defect report to previous revisions of the standard, you can read some discussion here: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/2612.

It seems that Microsoft's standard library implementation as well as LLVM's libc++ apply the issue resolution also to previous standard revision modes, while GCC's libstdc++ doesn't. I could not find any bug report or similar discussing the latter's choice.